# EF Core and update the same record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety

I have a simple situation but I am afraid that it will throw exceptions sometimes.
Case: We have X users in the application and these users can search for some data.
If any data will be found then that data should be incremented on one of its fields.
For example:

```
class Book {
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public int FoundCounter {get; set;}
}
```

and if we will find a book then we should increment "FoundCounter" field.

It's very easy but if we have X users and these users are using search then we can situation when a few users will find exactly the same book and then all threads will want to update the same record.

I'm afraid that then I will get an exception.
I use C# and EF Core.

Is there any way to do it safely?

Best Regards,
Krzysztof.

Comment: "Book" is one entity and all Books have a FoundCounter column.

Comment: Of course, but what my search finds 10,000 books?

Comment: The search engine can find a lot of books and on all of these books, I would like to increment this field. So for example, if I will find 100 books then I would like to increment 100 records by 1 value on all of found books.

Comment: But how useful is that information? Nobody actually *looks* at 100 (or 10,000) books. To me it's a meaningless number. It seems far more interesting to see which books (or other items) were actually opened/clicked or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't post comments because my reputation is too low. You might want to consider the question some more.  Can a book be found multiple times by the same user? If you do a search does it return many book records?  These are scenarios you need to consider and it will make the answer more complex. Let's say we just return a list of books and then select 1 book in the list, then we will increase the "FoundCounter".

When you get the record you can increment the count and then return the book record.

```
public async Task<Book> ReturnBook(bookId Id)
{

    using (var context = new DataContext())
    {
       var book = await context.Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == bookId);
       book.FoundCounter++
       context.SaveChangesAsync();

       return book;
    }   
}
```

This will increase your FoundCounter each time a record is retrieved. Again, there are more questions that need answered for this but this is the  most basic example of what I think you might be asking.

Comment: The search engine can find a lot of books and on all of these books, I would like to increment this field. So for example, if I will find 100 books then I would like to increment 100 records by 1 value on all of found books.

Comment: You would have to do something like return a list of books and iterate through that list to update the FoundCounter on each book, however this isn't going to be very performant and will end up being a lot more work on your system.  Say you have a widely used website and you are trying to track your analytics through EF the way you want to, I don't believe this is a good solution to implement. You'd be better off using some sort of analytics tool

Comment: You can do it fast in EF if you use an update for all records without iteration. That's not the problem. I'm afraid about threads when for example 100 users will find the same books and all of these threads run updates on the same books. It will be a collision and maybe I will get an exception but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can take care of the concurrency situation in EF core by using concurrency tokens.
This site has a good example and description.
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency

Comment: Thank you, it was what I was looking for but I have decided to resolve my problem in a different way - I will create a dedicated table with one column (IDBook) and always I will be inserting data there (after search and with search results). Then I won't have a problem with concurrency and still, I will have information about the counter when I will do Count on the table with where section for ID Book.